# Clicking on existing profile picture to upload and change image.

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have made a user profile card where the user can click on choose file to select and upload an image.
[image]

Everything works fine however I would like to change it so instead of having to click on "choose file" and then click on "upload", the user can just click on the existing image and be brought to the select image screen:
[image]

and once they have selected a image and pressed open, the image is automatically changed?

This is my code to display the user profile card.

```
  <?php
        //query to see if the user has uploaded a profile picture.
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_image WHERE userid = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i",$_SESSION['userid']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $userImage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    ?>   


  <h1>User's Profile</h1>
  <?php if($userImage['is_set'] == 0){
            echo '<img src="profile_pics/default-profile-pic.png"/>'; 
   }
        else{
            echo '<img src="'.$userImage['image_dir'].'"/>';
   }
   ?>
   <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+file+upload+custom+button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `<label>` tag attached the file input to trigger the open box or you can use a click handler on the image that triggers a click on the file input.

```
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('h1 + img').click();
});
```

To get the file to upload immediately when selected you have to attach a *change* event handler for the image input. Then submit the form in it. You would have to change the submit button name to something other than submit to get this to work.

```
document.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener('change', function(){
    this.form.submit();
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Is the second option for the upload button to be automatically triggered once a user selects an image?

Comment: Yes, when you select an image the *change* event will fire and the code will submit the form, granted you change the button name.

Comment: I've changed the buttons name to upload and enclosed the querySelector in <script> tags but the form action is not triggering. Is there anything I've missed out?

Comment: Thank you its triggering the form now. One last question in my php code does the if(isset($_POST['upload'])) still work since im not actually pressing the submit button?

Comment: No, since it wasn't clicked

Answer (score 8):

Use a `<label>` (with `for` targeting the `id` on the file field):

```
<label for="fileField"><img src="..."></label>

<input type="file" id="fileField" name="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: this works but the choose file is still visible, how would I get that to be hidden?

Comment: try to hide it with CSS, just hiding the "input" tag.
`#filefield { display: none; }`, or put inner style directly into input HTML tag - `<input style="display: none;" ...`

Comment: Is there anyway for the upload button to be automatically triggered once a user selects an image?

Comment: Sure, trigger a `submit` event on the form, or use AJAX to upload just the file somewhere. Both techniques are easily Googled.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="fileField"><img src="..." height="100px" width="100px"></label>

<input type="file" id="fileField" name="file" accept="image/*" hidden="true">
```

Using **hidden = "true"**, you can invisible the choose file.

Using **height** and **width** inside the img tag, you can adjust the image size.